# Using Kotlin and Firebase to trigger a sendEmailVerification with onAuthStateChanged callback

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, listener, kotlin

I'm starting a new Android project and decided to use **Kotlin** and **Firebase** within, right now I'm able to create users successfully using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` on my SignupActivity and my users are logged in successfully when createUserWithEmailAndPassword is finished.

Now I'm trying to get it further using the callback event that is triggered on [FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener) using `onAuthStateChanged(FirebaseAuth auth)` but the listener that I'm creating inside my `onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)`function isn't get triggered and my lack of experience converting Java code to Kotlin isn't helping me to identify the root problem.

I have some Java example code to base on that goes like this:

### Java example

```
onCreate(...//
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            // User is signed in
            // NOTE: this Activity should get onpen only when the user is not signed in, otherwise
            // the user will receive another verification email.
            sendVerificationEmail();
        } else {
            // User is signed out

        }
        // ...
    }
};
```

### My Kotlin code

```
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { auth ->
        val user = auth.currentUser
        if(user != null){
            // User is signed in
            Log.d(TAG, "Signed in")
            Toast.makeText(this, "User", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            sendVerificationEmail()
        }else{
            // User is signed out
            Log.d(TAG, "Signed out")
            Toast.makeText(this, "Null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

I put some log and toast elements for debugging purpose but neither of them are getting triggered, I'm thinking that the `onAuthStateChanged` is missing inside the **FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener** but I don't know how to fix it.

If anyone can give me some advice on what I'm doing wrong it'll be much appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Needless to ask but still, are you adding `AuthStateListener` to FirebaseAuth object?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? The only part that I'm using `AuthStateListener`is on the snippet I posted, do I need to put it in other part of my activity? Thanks @chandil03

Comment: You have just initialised `AuthStateListener` object, now you have to assign it to FirebaseAuth object to tell this is the guy to contact when auth state changes.

Comment: Thanks @chandil03, how can I make this assignment? When I used **createUserWithEmailAndPassword** it was pretty simple (Just declare the FirebaseAuth object and call the method) but I don't know which assign is missing on the listener.

Comment: check for something like add..stateListener() method on firebaseAuth object, created by FirebaseAuth.getInstance() method.

Comment: struggling with the same issue now, did you manage to get onAuthStateChanged called?

Comment: Yes khusrav, it was almost the same way you did, have a good day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what has helped me, pay attention on the parenthesis when calling `addAuthStateListener` - being new to kotlin I used `{ }` curly ones:

```
    public override fun onStart() {
      super.onStart()
      firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    }

    public override fun onPause() {
       super.onPause()
       firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    }
```

Comment: Yes @khusrav, this was the way I assigned the `AuthStateListener` to `FirebaseAuth` object to tell it to contact when auth state changes, the only thing is that I used onStart() and onStop() when solving this.

Comment: I used this commit as base and @samtstern from Google explained to me why they removed the `AuthStateListener` from Google Firebase examples, I hope it helps someone: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/commit/1c0456309a9b7f2afe850ee3283bf34a36080799#comments

Comment: They don't recommend using it anymore?

Comment: oh, ok, so it still can be used like before. But looking at the code in the commit, it looks cleaner without it.

Comment: They do, but earlier they had problems because the behavior of AuthStateListener was different and developers got confused, to resolve it they made some new AuthListener called `IdTokenListener` with the old behavior, check the link I posted and go to the comments section. Is good to know I think.